# dropdownlist on gridview selectindexchange error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

hi hope all you are fine

i have a grid view

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Refrence No">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="RefrenceNo" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Projects">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="Projects" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="onTextChange" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and in code

```
Protected Sub onTextChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView2.Rows(GridView2.EditIndex)

    Dim ddlProjects As DropDownList = CType(row.FindControl("Projects"), DropDownList)
    Dim txtProjects As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("RefrenceNo"), TextBox)

    txtProjects.Text = ddlProjects.Text
End Sub
```

i want to fill text box with drop down list change value but in run time error comes

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Parameter name: index

Line 68:         Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView2.Rows(GridView2.EditIndex)

please help

Comment: This is not a `C#` question. I have removed that tag and replaced it with `vb.net`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can explain you what the error is telling..

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView2.Rows(GridView2.EditIndex)
```

Check the value of `GridView2.EditIndex`..There is no row in the particular Gridview with that index..So you may check the value of **EditIndex**..

Comment: thank you so much guy. i have apply this code for giving your idea.

Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = CType(sender, DropDownList).NamingContainer
        Dim rowindex As Integer = CType(gvrow, GridViewRow).RowIndex

        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView2.Rows(rowindex)